# blowfish ecb with openssl doesn't give the expected result

Tags: encryption, openssl, ecb, blowfish

I do the following via the Linux CLI:

```
printf '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff' > plaintext.txt
openssl enc -bf-ecb -e -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.txt -nosalt -K FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF -p
```

I then read the contents of ciphertext.txt with `<?= bin2hex(file_get_contents('ciphertext.txt')); ?>` and I get this:

```
5aacfb5a8dc0155dd0269124c9e81789
```

According to https://www.schneier.com/code/vectors.txt, however, the result is this:

```
51866fd5b85ecb8a
```

That ciphertext.txt is twice as long as the test vector result makes sense because of padding. But shouldn't the first eight bytes of ciphertext.txt match the test vector?

Doing the above with `des-ecb` (same plaintext and same key) gives the same output that https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/testvectors/bc/des/Des-64-64.test-vectors mentions (Set 3, vector#255) so it seems like my test methodology is correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-bf-ecb` cipher is expanding the key to 128 bits by zero extending it.

The output from `-p` is the telltale here:

```
$ openssl enc -bf-ecb -e -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.txt -nosalt -K FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF -p
key=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000
```

Blowfish is defined for 32-448 bit keys, and it appears the OpenSSL implementation chose 128 bits as the size to use, and added zero-extension of shorter keys as a 'convenience'.

Compare this with `-des-ecb`, where DES is only defined for 64 bit keys:

```
$ openssl enc -des-ecb -e -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext-des.txt -nosalt -K FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF -p
key=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```